# $Pr(X<v)$ on a dice roll

Tags: probability

If you have a 6-sided dice, what is the probability of getting less that $k$ on it? I am really trying to figure out the $Pr[U=u \cap V=v]$ but I assume that that is equivalent to calculating $Pr[u < v]$. Am I correct in assuming this?

Answer (score 1):

It's the sum of getting $1$,$2$...,$k-1$. As getting any of the dices is $1/6$, then sum of those are $(k-1)/6$.

Answer (score 0):

if you throw a dice once, then you have the probability of 1/6 to throw a one.

What ist the probability to throw a two ?

What is then the probability to throw a one or a two ?

What do you mean with the following sentence ?

> I am really trying to figure out the p(U=u and V=v) but I assume that that is equivalent to saying the p(u

greetings,

calculus

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to define the variables. U=min(x,y) V=max(x,y) where x and y are two separate dice rolls.